# Add visualforce page in sites and display lookup object record

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, custom-domain, custom-url

1. Create a visualforce page for login.
2. when user login successful then display the second page for record detail.
3. I can add login page as a site home page and detail page add in Site Visualforce Pages.
4. Now I can preview my site login page successfully working but when it reloads second-page user details not disable.
5. only the data table was disabled.
6. But when I can preview separate visual force page then display all records in my data table.

   How can I solve it?

Comment: Please include code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I can resolve the error. I had a mistake in permission.